# How to import a bean which comes from a configuration bean conditional on another class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm using a 3rd party dependency in my Spring Boot project (version 2.6.3) which has the following classes:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.cloud.vault", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureAfter(ApacheHttpClientAutoConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public class VaultServiceAutoConfiguration {
    // ...
}


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({VaultServiceProperties.class})
@ConditionalOnBean(VaultServiceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class VaultServiceFacadeConfiguration {
  private final VaultServiceProperties vaultServiceProperties;

  @Autowired
  public VaultServiceFacadeConfiguration(VaultServiceProperties properties) {
    this.vaultServiceProperties = properties;
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(VaultServiceFacade.class)
  public VaultServiceFacade vaultServiceFacade(
      @Qualifier("runtime") VaultServiceTemplate vaultServiceTemplate) {
        // ...
  }
}
```

I set `spring.cloud.vault.enabled=true` in my `bootstrap.yml`.

In my project I import the dependency and created a component class:

```java
@Component
public class MyVault {
    private VaultServiceFacade vaultServiceFacade;

    public MyVault(VaultServiceFacade vaultServiceFacade) {
        this.vaultServiceFacade = vaultServiceFacade;
    }
}
```

in order to use `VaultServiceFacade` bean which provides methods to interact with Hashicorp Vault instance. The problem is that I get this error: `No qualifying bean of type 'other.package.VaultServiceFacade' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

I don't understand why I get his error because my main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` so that auto-configuration is enabled. In addition if I try to inject `VaultServiceAutoConfiguration` bean **it works:**

```java
@Component
public class MyVault {
    private VaultServiceAutoConfiguration v;

    public MyVault(VaultServiceAutoConfiguration v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I did notice that the dependency has a file `spring.factories` with the following code:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  other.package.VaultServiceAutoConfiguration
```

So maybe only `VaultServiceAutoConfiguration` is "whitelisted" for auto-configuration, so I need to understand how to allow other beans from `other.package` to be injected in my project.

**EDIT2:** I managed to get this working by adding `@ComponentScan` on the `MyVault` class:

```java
@ComponentScan("other.package")
@Component
public class MyVault {
    private VaultServiceFacade vaultServiceFacade;

    public MyVault(VaultServiceFacade vaultServiceFacade) {
        this.vaultServiceFacade = vaultServiceFacade;
    }
}
```

I still don't understand why the `ComponentScan` works only on when added to `MyVault` class but is if I scan for this package from main it class it doesn't work:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"other.package"})
public class Application {

  // ...
}
```

Comment: How do you run your application? also try adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in `Application`

Answer (score 2):

`@ComponentScan` just works because you're very directly asking Spring to scan said package for any beans which it straight up does.

I can't tell why `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"other.package"})` doesn't work without trying it for myself but I guess the error you get is that the `other.package` beans get created and instead all other beans fail to exist (after all `other.package` is not the base package).

Finally, why doesn't you preferred conditional approach work?

Hard to tell without a simplified sample app to work with. I doubt it's because of `VaultServiceAutoConfiguration`, I've created a simplified project where the offending bean lies directly in said class and it loads just fine. Try moving your `VaultServiceFacade` definition to `VaultServiceAutoConfiguration` and remove `@AutoConfigureAfter(ApacheHttpClientAutoConfiguration.class)`, if that works you know it's something in `VaultServiceFacadeConfiguration` (or `@AutoConfigureAfter(ApacheHttpClientAutoConfiguration.class)` itself, maybe `@EnableConfigurationProperties({VaultServiceProperties.class})`?

Also, I used `application.properties` instead of `bootstrap.yml` but that's unlikely to be it.

Feel free to send a sample simplified project to work on and test your assumptions

Answer (score 0):

As the default value for the property is already true, I would not set it at all.
In order to explicitly configure the Facade try to
`@Import(VaultServiceFacadeConfiguration.class)`
in your SpringBootApplication.

Please check your dependencies. "other.package" looks very strange and does not look like a package name used by HashiCorp.